# How do I create a bat file that will load my website every 10 minutes?

Tags: batch-file

I have a .NET site on Godaddy that is slow to load initially because .net wants to compile all of the dlls before it serves the user. To circumvent this I want to create a scheduled task on that will hit the homepage every 10 minutes. I know how to navigate and use the scheduled task tool, I do not, however, know how to write a bat file.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the multiple free web services instead? i.e. https://uptimerobot.com/

Comment: will this work the same way?

Comment: Yeah. It will "load" your webpage every five minutes. Plus you will get notified it it the page fails to load.

Comment: Please make your comment an answer as this has helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a free monitoring service.
For example uptimerobot.com

Comment: gotta wait my two minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome, I'd look at the plug-ins that you can get. For example;

ChromeReload https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromereload/njoipeaphfnaplplihpbgndfojhdhmjo

Refresh-Monkey
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/refresh-monkey/ljngnafhejmefmijjoedbclkadhacebd

Easy-Auto-Refresh https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc